# how to lock existing data in rows in vf page

Tags: apex, visualforce

```
how to lock existing data in rows in vf page :
<tr width="400%">
                <td width="40%"><apex:outputlink value="/{!w.Opportunity_Detail1__r.id}" style="color:blue">{!w.Opportunity_Detail1__r.name} </apex:outputlink></td>
               <td width="40%">
               <div style="word-wrap:break-word; width:100px;" >
                 <apex:outputText value="{!w.AccountName1__c}"></apex:outputText>
               </div></td>
                <td width="60%">

                   <apex:outputtext value="{0, number, #,###}" style="float:center;"> <apex:param value="{!w.Amount11__c}" /></apex:outputtext>

               </td>
               <td width="40%">
               <div style="word-wrap:break-word; width:100px;" >
                 <apex:outputText value="{!w.Stage11__c}"></apex:outputText>
               </div></td>
                <td width="40%">{!w.Odds_of_Winning11__c}</td>
                <td width="40%"><apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}"> <apex:param value="{!w.Close_Date11__c}"/> </apex:outputText></td>
                <td width="40%">{!w.Direct_Gross_Margin11__c}</td>
                <td width="40%">{!w.Proactive_Reactive_proposal1__c}</td>
                <td width="40%">
               <div style="word-wrap:break-word; width:100px;" >
                 <apex:outputText value="{!w.Opportunities_Comments1__c}"></apex:outputText>
               </div></td>           
                <td width="40%">{!w.Weighted_Deal_Value_1__c}</td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Do you mean locking to prevent editing, or lock into a specific location on the page?

Answer (score 1):

In your Apex class for your soql you can add **for update** keyword to lock the record.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your VISUAL FORCE  page as read-only or you can declare the controller method as read-only. Please see this link http://sfdcmaniac.blogspot.in/2013/09/read-only-mode-for-visualforce-page-and.html?m=1